# What is the proper way to pass variable strings to `shell-command-to-string`?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script

```
$ cat ~/foo.sh

#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2
```

I'm trying to call this from emacs. My `elisp` function is

```
(defun foo (word1 word2)
  "Print these two words."
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-string "Enter first word: ")
    (read-string "Enter second word: ")))
  (shell-command-to-string "bash ~/foo.sh %s %s" word1 word2))
```

This, however, yields an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Yields an error" isn't terribly helpful. A good question quotes the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) :

```
(defun foo (word1 word2)
  "Print these two words."
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-string "Enter first word: ")
    (read-string "Enter second word: ")))
  (shell-command-to-string (format "~/foo.sh %s %s" word1 word2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> will tell you that `(shell-command-to-string COMMAND)` is the general form for that function, so it is clear that `(shell-command-to-string "bash ~/foo.sh %s %s" word1 word2)` is not valid.

Use `format` as Håkon Hægland has shown, but you should always process your arguments with `shell-quote-argument` to ensure the formatted shell command is correct.